# Jackson Polymorphic Deserialization with Spring Boot | JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, marshalling, jackson-databind

I am using @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes to serialize/deserialize the entity.

Below is code which I am doing

1. OrganizationDTO.java

```
public class OrganizationDTO {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    List<? extends EmployeeDTO> employees;
    //getter and setter
}
```

2. EmployeeDTO.java (Parent class)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @Type(value = FullTimeEmployeeDTO.class, name = "full"),
        @Type(value = PartTimeEmployeeDTO.class, name = "part")
})
public abstract class EmployeeDTO {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //getter and setter
}
```

3. FullTimeEmployeeDTO.java (Child Class)

```
@JsonTypeName("full")
public class FullTimeEmployeeDTO extends EmployeeDTO {
    private int salary;
    //getter and setter
}
```

4. PartTimeEmployeeDTO.java (Child Class)

```
@JsonTypeName("part")
public class PartTimeEmployeeDTO extends EmployeeDTO {
    private int hourlyRate;
    //getter and setter
}
```

5. Organization Controller

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<ResponseUtil<Employee>> save(@RequestBody OrganizationDTO organization) {     
        organizationService.save(organization);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseUtil<Employee>("Data Saved Successfully."), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I am trying to call this endpoint from postman with this below data.

```
{
    "name": "My Organization",
    "employees": [
        {
            "type": "full",
            "name": "Vinit Solanki",
            "salary": 200
        },
        {
            "type": "full",
            "name": "Viren Shah",
            "salary": 300
        }
    ]
}
```

I am getting the exception as below.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-29T10:35:29.146+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between Object entries\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10, column: 21] (through reference chain: com.example.demo.dto.OrganizationDTO[\"employees\"]->java.util.ArrayList[1])",
    "path": "/organizations"
}
```

I wonder the same implementation is working while trying to convert the string JSON to `OrganizationDTO` object via `readValue()`. Below is an example of it.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        OrganizationDTO orgDTO = mapper.readValue(
                "{\n" +
                        "    \"name\": \"My Organization\",\n" +
                        "    \"employees\": [\n" +
                        "        {\n" +
                        "            \"type\": \"full\",\n" +
                        "            \"name\": \"Vinit Solanki\",\n" +
                        "            \"salary\": 200\n" +
                        "        },\n" +
                        "        {\n" +
                        "            \"type\": \"full\",\n" +
                        "            \"name\": \"Vinit Solanki\",\n" +
                        "            \"salary\": 130\n" +
                        "        }\n" +
                        "    ]\n" +
                        "}",
                OrganizationDTO.class);

    }
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your end-point is not receiving the full json string (`Unexpected end of input`). Can you check/turn on logs on spring-boot and see what is the string that it is trying to deserialize into `OrganizationDTO`?